# What "meta-dimension" do algebraic numbers have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, computer-algebra-systems

actually what I am asking for is "how many ways do there exist to create a real number out of a sequence of coefficients?" there is the solution of polynomials through radicals, some polynomials can be solved in terms of hypergeometric functions, then there are the roots of unity (which basically are algebraic numbers corresponding to polynomial solutions P to sin(x*n)=P_n(sin(x)) and the same for cos -- always forget how those polynomials are called). are there any other solutions for polynomials expressed in formulas using specially introduced functions? I suspect some algebraic numbers can be represented as some kind of integrals, i.e. just like those hypergeometric functions. however, just defining a function which maps coefficients onto an infinite sequence of digits for a float doesn't count here: my question is if one would create such a function, how many other functions must be included into it to generally solve all polynomial equations generally as the output of a polynomial in those functions. i.e roots are binary functions, roots of unity are unary functions, hypergeometric functions are functions taking many numbers as input. do these 3 suffice to express all algebraic numbers as a polynomial in these with input being again polynomial in these functions and so on? or does one need some other functions too? what research is being done in this respect?

my goal is to represent algebraic numbers in the computer in order to replace the float datatype by a datatype of infinite precision. any work being done in that direction?

Comment: Some of your word combinations and phrases don't parse very well or make sense: "onto an infinite sequence of digits for a float"; "roots are binary functions, roots of unity are unary functions, hypergeometric functions are functions taking many numbers as input" (I just realized in this last one you are probably talking about parameters in the expressions). I suspect in order to get an "answer" that you can understand, you should describe your math background.

Comment: yepp, sorry, this is a major shortcoming on my side. I understand most mathematical publications, so don't worry there. however, I haven't learned yet to express myself well. (I suspect that's mainly because I try to learn talking in a comprehensible way towards programmers, math talk is secondary to me.) so if you know any research paper of interest for me, pray tell.

Comment: You do realize that as soon as we use even a sine or exponential, we leave the domain of algebraic numbers, right? Even ignoring or accounting for that, you're likely to end up with a datatype whose representation for a number is basically an encoding of the computation that produces it, and you'll have to run that computation with regular floating-point to have any idea what the number's value is. This runs into all the problems of using rationals for everything, but worse.

Comment: I don't have a good feel for what you're looking for, but these might be of possible interest to you: [*What is a closed-form number?*](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9805045); [Wikipedia page for *Computable number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number); [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0480.pdf); [this paper](http://www-sst.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/~wwwti/zheng/publications/1998/mfcs98.pdf); [Wikipedia page for *Transcendence theory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_theory); [this paper](http://gelfond-100.mi.ras.ru/pdf/adamczewski.pdf).

Comment: @user2357112: Actually, there is some benefit for high precision calculations, in that you can design the library to compute only the amount of precision you need, and automatically generate more precision on the fly.

Comment: @Dave L Renfro: thanks, but these papers talk mainly about non-algebraic numbers. wikipedia even says all algebraic numbers are computable, without explaining how.

Comment: @user2357112: sine is algebraic for all rational multiples of the full circle as input. same with e^ix. the P_n I mention above are polynomials derived from addition-theorems of sin and cos. so P is a sequence of polynomials thereby solutions are algebraic. as for rationals, x<y can be checked with few operations. I'd like the same possibility for algebraic numbers. Dave's 1st suggestion mentioned that ellyptic, hypergeometric and theta functions (maybe others) cover the whole set of algebraic numbers. sadly no literature is mentioned. well, that's what I'm looking for, an exhaustive list!

Comment: Regarding the computability of algebraic numbers, I believe this will follow from a sufficiently constructive proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, such as can be found in the following paper: P. C. Rosenbloom, *An elementary constructive proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra*, **American Mathematical Monthly** 52 #10 (December 1945), 562-570.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my goal is to represent algebraic numbers in the computer in order to replace the float datatype by a datatype of infinite precision. any work being done in that direction?

Probably the easiest way to do that is to represent an algebraic number via its minimal polynomial along with enough information to pick out which root of the minimal polynomial it is. (e.g. a floating point approximation, or alternatively intervals of rational numbers that bound the real and imaginary parts such that only one root of the polynomial satisfies these bounds)

Comment: that's the first thing that comes to mind. but, you then lose the field-structure of algebraic numbers. given a minimal polynomial of x and y, how do you compute the minimal polynomial for x+y and x*y? how do you test x<y? and even if you can, how do you know which root to use if some solutions are indistinguishable within the computer's accuracy, for example when you run out of memory? once you introduce bounds you aren't infinite precision anymore, you then are limited to how exactly you can store these bounds.  this representation isn't an infinite-precision drop-in replacement for floats!

Comment: There are formulas involving resultants for computing a polynomial with root $x+y$ from a polynomial with roots $x$ and a polynomial with root $y$. There are lattice techniques as well. The infinite precision comes from the fact we're representing algebraic numbers by their minimal polynomial; the  only point of the bounds is to pick out which root (although they help with the lattice techniques). You can run out of memory, but that is a problem for *any* representation, since there are more real numbers (or even just integers) than there are possible ways you can set/clear bits in memory.

Comment: And there are all sorts of variations on this scheme one can come up with. Worried about requiring too much precision to distinguish roots? Then instead find a number field $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ that your number lies in so that you can write it as a linear combination of powers of $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is chosen to be easily distinguishable from its conjugates; e.g. $\alpha$ being large and positive while all of its conjugates are less than $1$ in magnitude.

Comment: thanks, some reference would have been nice though. thinking about it, also Dave's pointers were very helpful.